# R tm TermDocumetMatrix won't show all

Tags: r, tm

When I using TM, I'm trying to show the TermDocumentMatrix with inspect(), the result is not all the matrix, just part of it.

I am really confused.

Here is the result of my TDM:

```
> tdm
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 84, documents: 1)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 84/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 16
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

Here is the result of inspect():

```
> inspect(tdm)
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 84, documents: 1)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 84/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 16
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
               Docs
Terms           1
  “            3
  and           6
  both          2
  building      2
  entrepreneurs 2
  impacts       2
  political     2
  social        3
  the           4
  they          4
```

This is my R Version and the tm package:

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.5

locale:
[1] zh_TW.UTF-8/zh_TW.UTF-8/zh_TW.UTF-8/C/zh_TW.UTF-8/zh_TW.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tm_0.7-1   NLP_0.1-10

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 parallel_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0    Rcpp_0.12.11   slam_0.1-40
```

Thanks for all your answers !

Comment: You only seem to have one document in your `corpus`. Thus your `tdm` is really just a vector of terms and frequency for that document. Check how you created your `tdm` perhaps.

Comment: This `corpus` is just for test, the paragraph for test is only about 100 words. I'm using `tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(txt, control = list(wordLengths = c(2, Inf)` to create  `tdm`. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: If your `txt` came from a `VectorSource` and if it has only one paragraph, then it will be interpreted as only one `document`

Comment: I know there is only one document, but my question is why `inspect(tdm)` won't show all the words in the TDM, just part of it. Anyway, **Florian**'s method is work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a small matrix you can just typecast it to a matrix.

`as.matrix(tdm)`

Answer (score 0):

Use more than one document to get a `tdm` with more than one column.

```
> text <- stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(3)
[1] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nullam imperdiet nunc maximus in diam, orci sed. Vitae urna sapien eu torquent cursus neque. Sed class. Diam neque massa sed ac vestibulum commodo fames. Commodo fermentum lacinia integer quisque sed in augue condimentum venenatis ut. Nunc cubilia malesuada auctor sem non nisl. Nec augue sem potenti ac odio sed penatibus augue sagittis. Aliquam, maecenas taciti sed porta nullam accumsan lacus. Scelerisque hac dictum ut lacinia curabitur in lobortis diam."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[2] "Nibh vel nullam lectus lectus. At praesent nullam in aenean himenaeos morbi. Lorem ligula ut consectetur felis iaculis justo libero nec libero, ipsum, cubilia. Suscipit convallis. Ac primis quis curabitur non eget mi dictumst. Habitasse ipsum amet purus eros, mauris sed justo, amet, eu vehicula euismod. Purus neque massa hac et tellus. Pellentesque sit non eget porttitor ac. Condimentum amet hendrerit mauris eu amet duis tortor. Sociis dolor non, bibendum. Nibh vehicula nulla ad aliquam, facilisi ante cursus sem egestas eu. Metus donec ultricies interdum eu proin, diam cubilia vestibulum, fermentum mauris mauris. Vel ut nec a et sit turpis sit urna nec. Nulla cursus dolor maecenas parturient sed turpis nunc class. Dolor leo varius non eget, sed pharetra orci nulla molestie, phasellus. Nec mus vitae feugiat."
[3] "Ultrices et arcu, porta, donec vel metus vel euismod facilisi fusce. Curae ac auctor sed risus in sit sapien sed eros diam sed sit, nisl lacus sed. Quis, aliquam sed nisl nisl sed tempor urna volutpat vel curabitur. Vehicula dignissim ante ipsum magna mus quam. Molestie in vel sed, id, platea a. Suspendisse posuere, rhoncus nec porttitor hendrerit sociosqu auctor eu mattis neque. In in lobortis ut fusce, congue imperdiet sit sed molestie. Eget sem augue mauris eu consequat duis sed. Litora ante placerat rutrum fringilla phasellus lorem. Maximus ac et himenaeos praesent ullamcorper nascetur, pretium vitae."                                                                                                                                                                                                              
> corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(text))
```

In the above, `corpus` has three documents.

```
> tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus); inspect(tdm)
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 188, documents: 3)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 250/314
Sparsity           : 56%
Maximal term length: 13
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
        Docs
Terms    1 2 3
  amet   4 0 0
  augue  1 1 2
  dolor  3 1 0
  dui    0 2 1
  mauris 0 2 2
  neque  2 1 1
  nulla  1 2 1
  sed    4 1 2
  sed,   2 0 2
  velit  0 1 3
```

Comment: Actually, I have to read a pdf, each page will be set as a document. When I trying to inspect the TDM, it always just show a little part of it. But the `as.matrix()` method works for me. Anyway, thanks for your reply!